# Как работают циклы while, for

Tags: c++

Я до сих пор не пойму, как работает цикл while, откуда разработчики берут формулы, которые пишутся в скобках после цикла while и for?

Answer (score 4):

Все циклы можно записать через условный оператор и безусловный переход.

Например,

`for (A; B; C) {D;}` можно переписать как `A; while (B) {D; C;}`

`while (A) {B;}` - как  `a: if (A) {B; goto a;}`

Ну, и далее в том же духе. Очень рекомендуется сравнить полученные результаты с изображающими их блок-схемами. И уже в таком наглядном виде Вы легко сообразите какое условие нужно вписать. Главное помнить, что значением "ЛОЖЬ" в Си принято 0, а любое остальное значение - "ПРАВДА". Т.е. `if (0) {A;}` - блок инструкций не будет выполняться, а `if (1) {A;}` - будет выполняться всегда. Также следует обратить внимание, что у разных операторов есть возвращаемые значения. Это позволяет делать конструкции вида `a=b=0;`, т.к. `b=0` возвращает `0`, а затем уже присваивает это `a`. И в таких случаях новички обычно путаются и делают ошибки в условиях операторов if, while и do-while.

Comment: старый добрый способ вычисления i-го числа из ряда Фиббоначи.
<pre>
int i=8, a1, a2;
for (a1=a2=1; i>2; a1=(a2+=a1)-a1) i--;
</pre>
попробуйте попериписывать на другие циклы с эквивалентым кол-вом кода.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не поверите, но разработчики придумывают их сами что бы задать необходимое действие цикла! Как работают циклы описано в каждом учебнике по C/C++.