Почему итератор downto менее предпочтителен чем while при итерации по модифицируемой строке?
Недавно встретился вот такой код с фильтрацией строки:
s := 'Some text 123 and more text.';
for I := 1 to length(s) do
  if not (s[i] in ['0'..'9','.']) then
    Delete(s, i, 1);

В комментариях справедливо замечено:

Кроме того, нельзя итерироваться по строке и в то же время модифицировать её. В крайнем случае можно использовать downto для итерации с конца строки, но лучше заменить for цикл на while.

Почему нельзя итерироваться по строке и в то же время модифицировать её - очевидно. Однако почему downto тоже считается чем-то "крайним" и менее предпочтительным, чем while? Всегда казалось, что downto это простой валидный способ итерации. В идеале, хотелось бы увидеть конкретный пример когда downto приводит к ошибкам, а while отрабатывает корректно.

почему downto тоже считается чем-то "крайним" и менее предпочтительным, чем while - кем считается?

@Grundy Комментатором к вопросу по ссылке )  Мне кажется, это не стоило задавать отдельным вопросом, достаточно было спросить там же в комментариях у автора утверждения (что тоже было сделано, а сейчас того комментария уже нет, похоже)

Мне показалось полезным иметь отдельный вопрос и ответ по этой теме, чтобы в будущем на него ссылаться.

@Kromster Возможно. Просто я боюсь это было частное мнение в комментарии, ничем не подкреплённое )

@CrazyElf можете запостить это как ответ с минимальной мотивировкой, с меня плюс :-)

на сколько можно дубликатом закрыть? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435939/186999

или такой https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/33771/186999

или такой https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1166622/186999

@Grundy спасибо за ссылки! Вопрос не в скорости, а в корректности. Т.е. нужно либо мотивированное утверждение, что разницы нет, либо пример когда один из способов ломается (например, если бы удаление символа реаллоцировало строку, а итератор продолжал идти по старой строке, которую менеджер памяти бы уже деаллоцировал, например, особенно с учетом специфики управления строками в Delphi).

ни for ни while тут не работают с итераторами. По ссылкам не только и не столько про скорость речь была

@Grundy итератором я называл саму конструкцию итерирования по элементам сущности (а не Итератор который вы имеете ввиду). По ссылкам 1- совет не заморачиваться о производительности и утверждение что Java это все равно преобразует. 2 - утверждение что for можно переписать на while, а while на goto и совет читать учебник. 3 - более толковый, но без специфики Delphi-строк.

но без специфики Delphi-строк - а какая специфика тут может на что-то влиять?

@Grundy вот и мне интересно это же самое. Почему "В крайнем случае можно использовать downto для итерации с конца строки, но лучше заменить for цикл на while." Имхо ничего крайнего тут нет, downto такая же обычная итерация, а while в данном приложении неуклюж. Но я был бы рад оказаться неправ :-)

Да, вообще непонятно, откуда там вылез while. Если только из тех соображений, что вдруг кто-то запомнит, что для такого удаления таки можно использовать for, но не запомнит, что нужно использовать именно downto. Типа пусть он лучше запомнит, что for нельзя использовать, использовать можно while. Но ведь while тоже ещё нужно правильно написать, не факт, что это проще, чем for ... downto. %)

Оба подхода рабочие, downto даёт несколько более быстрый код.
Однако, если нужно обрабатывать много строк, или длинные строки, то постоянное перевыделение памяти (при Delete) приводит к квадратичной зависимости времени от длины строки, что при таком сценарии неприемлемо. А вот обработка строки на месте работает линейно и очень быстро.
Если строку портить нельзя, то нужно создать новую строку той же длины, и просто переписывать в неё хорошие символы (строки у нас, слава Вирту, мутабельные), после чего обрезать до нужной длины.
var
  t: DWord;
  i, j, n: Integer;
  s: string;
begin
  n := 1000000;

  s := '';
  for i := 1 to n do
    s := s + 'ab1';
  t := GetTickCount;
  for i :=  length(s) downto 1 do
      if s[i] in ['0'..'9'] then
          Delete(s, i, 1);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('downto %d',[GetTickCount - t]));

  s := '';
  for i := 1 to n do
    s := s + 'ab1';
  t := GetTickCount;
  i := 1;
  while i <= length(s) do begin
      if s[i] in ['0'..'9'] then
          Delete(s, i, 1)
      else
          inc(i);
  end;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('while %d',[GetTickCount - t]));

  s := '';
  for i := 1 to n do
    s := s + 'ab1';
  t := GetTickCount;
  j := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(s) do
      if s[i] in ['0'..'9'] then
         Inc(j)
      else
         s[i-j] := s[i];
  SetLength(s, Length(s) - j);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('inplace %d',[GetTickCount - t]));

Результаты
n = 100 000    
downto 656
while 1012
inplace 0

n = 1 000 000
downto 76391
while 115610
inplace 16


В while ошибка, если s := s + 'ab12';, то вторая цифра не убирается. А в остальном отличный ответ с примерами (пускай и не совсем по теме вопроса, которая больше про "почему же downto нельзя?", т.е. про валидность, а не про скорость), +1.

@Kromster Точно, поправил. Я не вижу причин, почему бы downto был невалиден. То, что в паскальном for пределы цикла считаются один раз - при данном подходе никак не влияет. Что-то ещё предположить - не знаю...

Никакой основательной причины выбирать while в данном случае нету. Данный вариант совершенно безопасен:
s := 'Some text 123 and more text.';
for I := length(s) downto 1 do
  if not (s[i] in ['0'..'9','.']) then
    Delete(s, i, 1);

Использование while следует предпочесть, если удаление идет не с текущей позиции.

Или когда делается удаление с помощью Replace, видимо.

Применять for и Replace в одном флаконе это явный косяк ))

Применительно к Pascal

разница заключается в невозможности изменить счетчик внутри цикла
for.

Из-за этого ограничения некоторые алгоритмы ожидающие изменение счетчика внутри цикла могут не работать.
Например, при проходе и удалении элемента не нужно изменять значение счетчика, чтобы не появлялись дырки в случае нескольких подряд идущих элементов для удаления.
В данном случае проблема решается проходом с конца коллекции.
Однако, в случае если следующее значение счетчика определяется каким-то алгоритмом - цикл for можно будет применить, только если заранее известно количество шагов

Вы намекаете на гораздо более сложные вещи, чем фильтрация строки :-)

@Kromster не, речь конкретно про ограничение for в паскале и его наследниках. Он буквально предназначен для циклов с известным количеством шагов
